# $\frac{N}{n}$; probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, probabilistic-method, telescopic-series

Here is an interesting identity:

> $$(n\leq N)~\dfrac{N}{n}=1+\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}+\dfrac{(N-n)(N-n-1)}{(N-1)(N-2)}+\cdots+ \dfrac{(N-n)(N-n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}{(N-1)(N-2)\cdots (n+1)n}. $$

I failed to prove that; but I was given a hint that we could do this by ***probability method***.

Then how to apply ***probability method*** to the proof? Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**: The nice answer below seems to not have applied probability theory. How to do it by probability theory?

Comment: If $n<N$, the identity does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: Can it be that you had in mind $(N-n-1)$ in the numerator?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve edited it.

Comment: Guess about the probability: Let $P(A)=\frac{N}{n}$. Then $P(A^c)=1-\frac{N}{n} = -(\text{RHS of original-1})$. Idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the sum as:
$$1+\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}+\dfrac{(N-n)(N-n-1)}{(N-1)(N-2)}+\cdots+ \dfrac{(N-n)(N-n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}{(N-1)(N-2)\cdots (n+1)n}\\
=1+\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}\left(1+\dfrac{N-n-1}{N-2}\left(1+\dfrac{N-n-2}{N-3}\cdots\left(1+\dfrac{2}{n+1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)\right)\\
\cdots =1+\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}\left(1+\dfrac{N-n-1}{n}\right)=1+\dfrac{N-n}{n}=\dfrac{N}{n}.$$
one observe that it "telescopes" from the end, leading to the final identity.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! By the way, induction is also an alternative way when reasoning, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, the same result can be obtained by induction.

Comment: Could you tell me whether it has something to do with probability theory?